# How to access an compatibility layer IViewPart’s (e4) MPart

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am porting an existing Eclipse plug-in to e4. From within a non-ported `IViewPart` I would like to access the view’s corresponding e4 `MPart` but couldn’t get the following to work reliably:

```java
EPartService partService = (EPartService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EPartService.class);
MPart part = partService.findPart(getSite().getId());
```

Placed in `createPartControlComposite)`
I sometimes get an `IllegalStateException` (“Application does not have an active window“).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the part service from the workbench as this only works when there is an active window.

Instead use the part service for the current window (which might not be active). You can get this in the IViewPart using:

```java
EPartService partService = getSite().getService(EPartService.class);

MPart part = partService.findPart(getSite().getId());
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. But allow me a quick follow-up question to better understand e4’s internal workings: If multiple instances of the `IViewPart` (with the same ID) are allowed, is the above **guaranteed** to find the `MPart` corresponding to the calling `IViewPart`/`IViewSite`?

Comment: No. You can only have multiple view parts with the same id if you use a secondary id as well. I'm not sure what e4 does with the secondary id.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Luckily, multiple copies of my view are not allowed, so this is not a problem for me – even though multiple windows, in which separate “single” views may exist, are possible. But AFAICT, these get separate `EPartService`s as well, so `findPart` should find the right view for the window.