# Save SWT widget properties to workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, e4, workbench

I have an E4 app with multiple views, which contain many SWT widgets including JFace TableViewers, TableViewerColumns, Tables ect. The file workspace.xmi is created/updated on close, but only with the properties of the views. Is it possible to store properties regarding these widgets in the workspace.xmi? So if the users changes the order of the columns, and restarts the app, the columns would be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

e4 `MApplicationElement` elements (such as `MPart`) have a

```
Map<String, String> getPersistedState()
```

method. You can set any values you like in the persisted state. They will be saved in the workbench.xmi and restored with the application is restarted.

It is up to you to design how you save the information about the SWT controls in the map.

Note: In an 3.x compatability mode view or editor you can get the `MPart` using

```
EPartService partService = getSite().getService(EPartService.class);

MPart part = partService.findPart(getSite().getId());
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, is there a way if it uses org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication?

Comment: If your RCP is using IApplication it is a 3.x compatability mode RCP rather than a pure e4 RCP. You can still get the MPart for a IViewPart see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556530/2670892)